# sorting list of lists by the second element of each sublist prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a list like `L = [[id1,avg1],[id2,avg2],....,[idN,avgN]]` and I want to sort this list by avg. I can't even start coding!
Any idea???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to look into `predsort`. For this you need to create a predicate that does comparisons for your list items.
For example:

`compareAvg(X,  [_,A1], [_,A2]) :- compare(X, A1, A2).`

then you can call

`predsort(compareAvg, [[1,2],[3,1],[5,3]],X).`